# SQL: Update a field only if a condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a column only if a condition is met. So for the column "Type", I want to change its value to "MongoDB" only if its current value isn't "MongoDB" This is what I'm using:

```
UPDATE Report
    SET Type = 
    CASE
       WHEN Type <> 'MongoDB' THEN 'MongoDB'
       ELSE Type
    END
    WHERE Id = x
```

The problem is:
Even when the Type is "MongoDB" I still see

> (1 row(s) affected)

in my SQL result. The whole point of this exercise was to reduce db operations when no needed. Why is it still modifying the record when the condition is not met?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not add the `Type <> 'MondoDB'` to your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The `CASE` statement isn't going to change WHICH records are affected. Only how they are affected. Instead, stick the criteria for WHICH records will be affected in the `WHERE` clause where it belongs.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not simplify it like this?

```
UPDATE Report
SET Type = 'MongoDB'
WHERE Id = x AND Type <> 'MongoDB'
```

But to answer your question you are still setting a records value even though its to the existing value. The record also comes back in the where clause so you will always have 1 row affected regardless of your CASE statement.